# Vertical-align text doesn't work for odd rows

Tags: css

I would like to `vertical-align: middle` the text in my rows thus I am differentiating odd and even rows. The code below works fine for odd rows however when applying the exact same code for even rows they are immediately transformed into columns. Any idea why?

```css
.wrc_pricing_table div.package_caption ul li.feature_style_2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 217.8px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  line-height: 1em !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.wrc_pricing_table div.package_caption ul li.feature_style_3 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 217.8px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  line-height: 1em !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I'm not using any HTML it's actually a plugin from wordpress i'm just adjusting the CSS to arrange rows, columns, color, font, etc. so it fits with the rest of the website. I just want my text to be in the middle of my rows but for some reason it only works with odd rows..

Comment: The plugin is generating the HTML for you. Can you direct us to a URL or view the source of the page to see the generated HTML?

Answer (score -1):

```
.wrc_pricing_table div.package_caption ul li {
}

.wrc_pricing_table div.package_caption ul li:nth-child(odd) {
}
```

Comment: it will be nice if you explain something, answer make no sense what you are trying to say.